# Em qual linguagem o StackOverflow foi desenvolvido?

Tags: debate

Me bateu essa dúvida, em qual linguagem foi desenvolvido o backend do fórum que utilizamos para tirar nossas dúvidas a respeito de desenvolvimento? Alguém sabe dizer?

Comment: C#. Asp.net MVC. Veja essa palestra que dá bastante detalhes : https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-peculiar-do-stack-overflow

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/297347)